# Running chrome in full screen using vb script

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have problem with a vb script i created to run chrome in full screen.
The script simulates the F11 key press when chrome starts.
The script works when i run it but when I set it to run on startup on Windows XP chrome does not go full screen.
This is the script i have.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "chrome" 
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{F11}"
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching Chrome with the command line switch "--full-screen".

It specifies if the browser should start in fullscreen mode, like if the user had pressed F11 right after startup. However, it seems it is ignored if the value of the "On Startup" setting is "Continue where you left off" (it works for the other two values).